# Problem with displaying percentile values in histogram

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have I believe relatively simple problem but I fail to find a solution to what I am doing wrong. I have a df of 4m + rows such as:

```
        sum(bytes)
0       2.452768e+08
1       3.781524e+09
2       2.897799e+09
3       1.851381e+09
4       1.185865e+10
...     ...
4159349 2.515966e+08
4159350 1.719197e+06
4159351 7.499110e+05
4159352 9.540200e+04
4159353 2.457000e+03
```

dtype = sum(bytes) -> float64

I want to make a histogram with 10 bins here so I can see the percentile distribution of my values and check which value is say 10% top cut off value. I dud follwing:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(df['sum(bytes)'], bins=10)
```

and the output graph ended up like this:

[image]

Can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You didn't do anything wrong. The other bins contain relatively few values and are basically invisible given your current scale.

Comment: @BigBen how can I then rescale the bin sizes so I can spread my entires more evenly?

Comment: you can try and use log on the results in order to spread them

Comment: You can also create a boxplot to get a feeling of how the data is distributed.  To further explore the data, the seaborn package offers a.o. [kde plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html), [strip plots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html) or [boxenplots](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxenplot.html).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was indeed in need of a log scale :)